# Crack ipod touch back up password

Tags: backup, ipod-touch, password-recovery

My mother passed a week ago. And all of the funeral plans, pictures of us, are on an ipod touch back up. I guess under all the stress, I forgot the backup password. It was made months ago. ( The password ) This is all I have left, can you help me? I'm desperate.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your situation. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and will likely be closed. Perhaps try http://superuser.com.

Comment: @Eric In my experiences with death (= 1/2), I would perhaps consult a reputable psychologist or expert on hypnosis. Remembering the password is probably the least damageable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this forum thread](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=217247):

1. Back up the encrypted files. Do this at least three or four times in at least two or three different geographical locations (e.g. put a copy on a flash drive and put it in safe deposit and upload a copy to Skydrive or another reputable backup site, perhaps email it to yourself if it's small enough). Keep at least two copies on your computer too to make sure you don't have trouble when some decryption attempt fails.

   You can find it under `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup` on Windows or `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` on a Mac.
2. Start guessing. Do you still have the iPod? That would help tremendously. Start guessing. If you're on a Mac, try extracting the password from Keychain. Try [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/02/04/iphone_backup_cracker/) maybe. But no matter what, keep backups at hand if it doesn't work and tries to lock you out.
3. Maybe try to remember your password. Like I said in my comment above, try looking for some kind of hypnotherapy to try. It probably won't work but it's worth a shot.